# Algorithm to compute $\pi_1(M^3)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Given a triangulated closed compact 3-manifold $M^3$, is there an algorithm to compute a presentation for $\pi_1(M)$? Is there an algorithm to determine if for a fixed group $G$, we have $\pi_1(M) \cong G$?

Comment: 1) is easy, since you can just consider it as a CW complex and use a standard algorithm given in say Hatcher. 2) is harder, but still true. It's more or less equivalent to the classification of 3-manifolds.

Comment: The answer to 2) is no; it's already an undecidable problem to determine if a group (as given by a finite presentation) is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $S^3$, namely the trivial group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's not quite correct the way I interpreted the question. The groups we're working with here are not general groups, but rather 3-manifold groups, which is restrictive enough that the isomorphism problem becomes solvable. So one should be careful and say that $G$ is also a 3-manifold group, rather than being described by an arbitrary finite presentation, or of course you're right.

Comment: If $G$ has decidable word problem, there is an algorithm to decide if $G$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a hyperbolic 3-manifold. This is probably even true without assuming hyperbolicity. I will eventually find a reference.